# What are good resources on data modelling for business intelligence?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

We are a SaaS startup offering purchase & procurement solutions. The data model for operational transactions has been created (relational DB). We also want to offer analytics on those transactions to decision makers but using ad hoc queries to get this data out of the existing tables would be inefficient. What resources are out there on data modelling for business intelligence / data warehousing?

Comment: What have you found already? By the terms of our [faq#dontask], this feels like a highly subjective question, unless you can define all the key metrics you need your database to perform to. `Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.` Because you have a good answer below that really helps cut to the heart of figuring out what you need, I'm going to close this question in lieu of needing better requirements.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question itself, then @me in a comment and I'll reevaluate and give pointers.

Comment: Thanks. I'm completely new to the topic of data modelling for business intelligence and I was just looking for a resource that covers the basics, such as the one suggested below. Hence, at this point, I cannot be anymore specific. I might revisit the question once I have read the suggested book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend the [Data Warehousing Toolkit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471200247) by Ralph Kimball.  This is a solid book on dimensional modeling and provides many "soup to nuts" case studies.